# How to get a count of different values in one column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
account_no     store_no    chain
12             1           Yes
12             2           Yes
13             10          No
13             21          No
13             32          No
14             11          No
15             12          Yes
```

I want to count unique values of `Yes` & `No` in `chain` column w.r.t unique `account_no`. `account_no` can have duplicates since it has one to many relationship with `store_no`. Following is my expected output

```
Yes : 2
No :  2
```

I am using following command in pandas, but it gives me overall unique value count

```
df.groupby(['account_no', 'chain']).ngroups
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by columns `account_no` and `chain` and then count `chain` by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['account_no','chain'])['chain'].value_counts()
print (s)
No     2
Yes    2
Name: chain, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df.store_no == 1, 'chain'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, `store_no` could be different, not necessarily it will be 1 for all `account_no`

Comment: ok, you need just drop duplicates in "account_no".
try that:
df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'account_no')['chain'].value_counts()

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.